# Coverage.py gives coverage of TEST code not APP code

Tags: pytest, code-coverage

I have a test suite (unit and system tests) that test a web server (implemented in flaskr/**init**.py).

I don't know why, but after I made a change I can't remember, suddenly coverage -m no longer shows coverage of the actual application, but of the test code (the unit and system tests).

BEFORE: the web server code was displayed

```
Name                 Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover
------------------------------------------------------
flaskr/__init__.py      58      0     30      1    99%
------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                   58      0     30      1    99%
```

NOW: the testing code is instead displayed

```
Name                                       Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------
tests/conftest.py                             62      4    94%   59-61, 74
tests/system_tests/__init__.py                 0      0   100%
tests/system_tests/test_realendpoints.py     122      3    98%   12-14
tests/unit_tests/__init__.py                   0      0   100%
tests/unit_tests/test_config.py               10      0   100%
tests/unit_tests/test_mockendpoints.py       152      0   100%
utilities/utilities.py                        70      8    89%   70-71, 74-76, 84-86
------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        416     15    96%
```

I run pytest and coverage like this:

```
coverage run -m pytest --capture=sys --html=./pytest_report_flask.html --self-contained-html --junitxml=./pytest_report_flask.xml --full-trace -v --log-level=INFO --reruns 0
coverage report -m
```